# Does NET 5 have a class for storing geolocation data?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

Does `.NET 5` have a class for storing geolocation data? `.NET 4.8` had [`GeoCoordinate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinate.latitude?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0) class. Which is not available in `.NET 5` and documentation does not provide a link to new implementation.

Coordinates are stored in database of the backend server and I am looking for application model to represent them. The location will be shown on a map as a pin on the front end. I use Entity Framework Core and store the coordinates as decimals.

Comment: There are a bunch of NuGet packages which claim to supply this for .NET Core

Comment: That's *not* a .NET BCL class. That's part of an API that gives access to Windows location services.

Comment: In .NET Core perhaps the most common library used for spatial features is [NetTopologySuite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite). You'll have to use it sooner or later, as it's used by EF Core to provide spatial support for PostgreSQL and SQL Server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks a lot for your great answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.NET 5` does not have such class.

I have decided to use NuGet: [Geolocation](https://github.com/scottschluer/geolocation) which meets my needs without introducing any other unnecessary dependencies.

It supports `.NET 5`, `.NET Core`, `.NET framework`

Comment: That's not a good choice. The original class wasn't part of the BCL, it was a Windows API wrapper. In .NET Core, the [NetTopologySuite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite) package is used extensively (1M+ downloads) *and* used by EF Core to provide spatial features

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks a lot for you great answer.